# OS X Terminal Colors

Tags: macos, shell, terminal, colors

I just got a Mac after working with Ubuntu Linux for some time. Among the many things I'm trying to figure out is the absence of colors in my terminal window- like the ones that are shown (on Linux) when running `ls -la` or `git status`.

How can one activate colors in their shell?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to configure Mac Terminal to have color ls output](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/973899/how-to-configure-mac-terminal-to-have-color-ls-output)

Answer (score 804, accepted):

Here is a solution I've found to enable the global
[terminal colors](http://it.toolbox.com/blogs/lim/how-to-fix-colors-on-mac-osx-terminal-37214).

Edit your `.bash_profile` (since OS X 10.8) — or (for 10.7 and earlier): `.profile` or `.bashrc` or `/etc/profile` (depending on availability) — in your home directory and add following code:

```
export CLICOLOR=1
export LSCOLORS=GxFxCxDxBxegedabagaced
```

`CLICOLOR=1` simply enables coloring of your terminal.

`LSCOLORS=...` specifies how to color specific items.

After editing `.bash_profile`, start a Terminal and force the changes to take place by executing:

`source ~/.bash_profile`

Then go to `Terminal > Preferences`, click on the `Profiles` tab and then the `Text` subtab and check `Display ANSI Colors`.

*Verified on Sierra (May 2017).*

Comment: just did this by adding it to .bash_profile and it works. didn't work when I added it to .profile though. Thanks!

Comment: on mountain lion I modified my `/etc/profile` and it works. For some reason I did not have a `~/.bash_profile`
Thanks!

Comment: To @Morten and any others struggling with their bash profiles, see these answers for an explanation and a solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7780055/665488, http://superuser.com/a/244990.

Comment: @AlexSpencer you should be able to just create it: a text file called `.bash_profile` in your home directory containing the exports in the answer.

Comment: To make it work in your .bashrc, simply add `source .bashrc` to your .bash_profile. Don't forget to enter `source .bash_profile` after modifying the files.

Comment: [dotfiles/.aliases](https://github.com/mathiasbynens/dotfiles/blob/master/.aliases) has a great `export LS_COLORS` statement

Comment: command+c the code shown above, open terminal, vi ~/.profile, press i, arrow key down to the bottom, make sure it is a new line, command+v, press escape, type !wq, source ~/.profile, quit terminal, open terminal again, type ls, say byebye to black&white term.

Comment: Well, I made this one line command if anyone needs it ;)

`printf 'export CLICOLOR=1\nexport LSCOLORS=GxFxCxDxBxegedabagaced' >> ~/.bash_profile`

Comment: @Midas: try http://ohmyz.sh/. There are themes and is more powerful than the default shell.

Comment: You have to check `Displasy ANSI colors` from Preferences then, on El Capitan at least

Comment: Just tried, it works on macOS Sierra (10.12). After making changes to .bash_profile do not forget to:  
1. In terminal type, `source ~/.bash_profile`    
2. In terminal preferences, select 'Display ANSI colors' under profiles tab. @MatthewBordas
@JohnnyHuo

Comment: Worked it macOS Sierra (10.12). I edited ~/.profile and opened a new window. No other changes necessary.

Comment: If you want the same colors that Linux uses (at least Debian and Ubuntu), use `LSCOLORS=ExGxFxdxCxDxDxxbaDecac`

Comment: Nice work. More details on what the letters in the customization string mean, here: http://www.marinamele.com/2014/05/customize-colors-of-your-terminal-in-mac-os-x.html

Comment: I use a Mac M1 pro with macOS Monterey and the file who I need to edit is ~/.zprofile

Answer (score 137):

You can use the Linux based syntax in one of your startup scripts.  Just tested this on an OS X Mountain Lion box.

eg. in your `~/.bash_profile`

```
export TERM="xterm-color" 
export PS1='\[\e[0;33m\]\u\[\e[0m\]@\[\e[0;32m\]\h\[\e[0m\]:\[\e[0;34m\]\w\[\e[0m\]\$ '
```

This gives you a nice colored prompt.  To add the colored `ls` output, you can add `alias ls="ls -G"`.

To test, just run a `source ~/.bash_profile` to update your current terminal.

Side note about the colors:
The colors are preceded by an escape sequence `\e` and defined by a color value, composed of `[style;color+m`, then wrapped in an escaped `[]` sequence.
eg.

- red = `\[\e[0;31m\]`
- bold red (style 1) = `\[\e[1;31m\]`
- clear coloring = `\[\e[0m\]`

I always add a slightly modified color-scheme in the root's .bash_profile to make the username red, so I see clearly if I'm logged in as root (handy to avoid mistakes if I have many terminal windows open).

In `/root/.bash_profile`:

`PS1='\[\e[0;31m\]\u\[\e[0m\]@\[\e[0;32m\]\h\[\e[0m\]:\[\e[0;34m\]\w\[\e[0m\]\$ '`

For all my SSH accounts online I make sure to put the hostname in red, to distinguish if I'm in a local or remote terminal.  Just edit the `.bash_profile` file in your home dir on the server..  If there is no `.bash_profile` file on the server, you can create it and it should be sourced upon login.

If this is not working as expected for you, please read some of the comments below since I'm not using MacOS very often..

If you want to do this on a remote server, check if the `~/.bash_profile` file exists.  If not, simply create it and it should be automatically sourced upon your next login.

Comment: how do you edit bash_profile for ssh accounts online?

Comment: I like `PS1` better with `$PWD` instead of `\u`, as such: `PS1=\[\e[0;31m\]$PWD\[\e[0m\]@\[\e[0;32m\]\h\[\e[0m\]:\[\e[0;34m\]\w\[\e[0m\]\$ `

Comment: Here's some more explanation of the codes for the prompt: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Color_Bash_Prompt#Step_by_step.

Comment: These links might also be helpful: [ANSI color code escape sequences](http://ascii-table.com/ansi-escape-sequences.php).  [More on PS1 codes](http://bitmote.com/index.php?post/2012/11/19/Using-ANSI-Color-Codes-to-Colorize-Your-Bash-Prompt-on-Linux).

Comment: @Cawas `$PWD` will not work as intended - it will indeed be replaced with current directory, but when the variable is assigned - that is, the value that is the current directory will go into the value of the prompt and from then on changing directories will have no effect on the directory contained in the prompt. This has to do with basic shell variable assignment and evaluation.

Comment: Really like your red color root prompt suggestion :) Thanks!

Comment: works in Yosemite perfectly!

Comment: I was having issues getting PROMPT_COMMAND colors to display correctly in El Capitan (OS X 10.11) using these color codes. Turns out that when used in `PROMPT_COMMAND`, you need to use the `\033` syntax instead of `\e`. Example to add a colored timestamp before your prompt (include this in your `~/.bashrc` or `~/.bash_profile`): `PROMPT_COMMAND="${PROMPT_COMMAND}; echo; echo -e '\033[0;35m'\[\$(date +%F\ %T)\]'\033[m'"`

Comment: bold red (style 1) = \[\e[1;31m\] , its 31 not 3m. Thanks

Answer (score 46):

MartinVonMartinsgrün and 4Levels methods confirmed work great on Mac OS X Mountain Lion.

The file I needed to update was ~/.profile.

However, I couldn't leave this question without recommending my favorite application, [iTerm 2](http://www.iterm2.com/#/section/home).

iTerm 2 lets you load global color schemes from a file. Really easy to experiment and try a bunch of color schemes.

Here's a screenshot of the iTerm 2 window and the color preferences.
[image: iTerm2 Color Preferences Screenshot Mac]

Once I added the following to my ~/.profile file iTerm 2 was able to override the colors.

```
export CLICOLOR=1
export LSCOLORS=GxFxCxDxBxegedabagaced
export PS1='\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
```

Here is a great repository with some nice presets:

[iTerm2 Color Schemes on Github by mbadolato](https://github.com/mbadolato/iTerm2-Color-Schemes)

Bonus: Choose "Show/hide iTerm2 with a system-wide hotkey" and bind the key with [BetterTouchTool](http://www.boastr.de/) 
for an instant hide/show the terminal with a mouse gesture.

Comment: iTerm2 crashed often on my system, so i switched over to oh-my-zsh https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh. There are also themes available

Comment: Hey! Please change `baskerville` link to proper one. Seems wrong copy-paste.

Comment: @NickWoodhams, what is the color-theme you are using in the screenshot?

Comment: @IndradhanushGupta Not sure what color scheme that was, it was a while ago. But now I am using the Pure ZSH theme and loving it. https://github.com/sindresorhus/pure

Comment: this is a nice color scheme and what I needed to check the items types //dirs and etc

Comment: yay for including picture

Answer (score 20):

If you want to have your ls colorized you have to edit your ~/.bash_profile file and add the following line (if not already written) :

```
source .bashrc
```

Then you edit or create ~/.bashrc file and write an alias to the ls command :

```
alias ls="ls -G"
```

Now you have to type `source .bashrc` in a terminal if already launched, or simply open a new terminal.

If you want more options in your `ls` juste read the manual ( `man ls` ). Options are not exactly the same as in a GNU/Linux system.

Comment: A somewhat better option is to replace the 'alias' definition with 'export CLICOLOR=" "'.  This has the advantage of usually continuing to work even if you switch shells during a terminal session (as long as environment variables are inherited - aliases aren't).

Answer (score 7):

If you are using tcsh, then edit your `~/.cshrc` file to include the lines:

```
setenv CLICOLOR 1
setenv LSCOLORS dxfxcxdxbxegedabagacad
```

Where, like Martin says, LSCOLORS specifies the color scheme you want to use.

To generate the LSCOLORS you want to use, checkout this [site](https://geoff.greer.fm/lscolors/)

Comment: `bash` has been the default in OS X since October 2003.

Comment: I think you're right. I just got a new mac and it had bash as default. I guess IT kept setting up my macs at work to have tcsh by default.

Comment: The link is just awesome!

Answer (score 4):

Check what $TERM gives: mine is xterm-color and ls -alG then does colorised output.

Comment: well, on capitan with `xterm-256color`, I get no colours. `CLICOLOR` and `LSCOLORS` don't change that ):

Answer (score 2):

When I worked on Mac OS X in the lab I was able to get the terminal colors from using Terminal (rather than X11) and then editing the profile (from the Mac menu bar). The interface is a bit odd on the colors, but you have to set the modified theme as default.

Further settings worked by editing `.bashrc`.