# RVM not being found (Mac 10.7.3)

Tags: ruby, rvm, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I've done a lot of searching and there seem to be similar issues, but none that have helped me solve this problem.  I'm fairly new to Ruby, Rails, and -ix systems so that doesn't help much, either. :(

I was able to get RVM up and running along with the latest versions (1.9.3-p125 of Ruby and 3.2 of Rails).  However, when I exit terminal and come back in the system defaults are being used.  When I tried to change versions I received a "command not found".  I then tried just typing "rvm" and got:

```
-bash: rvm: command not found
```

I followed some other tutorial advice and modified my ~/.bashrc file to look like this:

```
    PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin # Add RVM to PATH for scripting
    echo '[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"' >> ~/.bashrc
```

but I'm still getting the exact same "command not found" even after exiting Terminal.

Any thoughts on how to get RVM working properly?  Everyone says use it, but it sure isn't simple...

Thanks a lot!
Greg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I followed some other tutorial advice and modified my ~/.bashrc file

Usually I modify .profile file on Mac OS X, and .bashrc on Linux. Try to modify .profile

Please check [How to fix Terminal not loading ~/.bashrc on OS X Lion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7780030/how-to-fix-terminal-not-loading-bashrc-on-os-x-lion) to know why Terminal doesn't load .bashrc file.

Comment: This worked.  I needed a .profile file.  I also needed a .screenrc file per the instructions at [link](https://rvm.io/workflow/screen/).  Thank you both for your help.  Selecting this answer since it specifically fixed the Mac issue.

Answer (score 1):

If you modify your `.bashrc` you either need to immediately `source` it or create a new shell to see the changes take effect.

The standard `rvm` procedure is to `source` the `rvm` script that is created. The [installation documentation](https://rvm.io/rvm/install/) covers most use cases.

If your `rvm` command is missing, it's possible that your `.bashrc` is not working as you expect. Is your `PATH` being modified as you've requested? If not you might have another issue.