# Cant use node.js after install

Tags: node.js, bash, command-line

After I have installed node, it works. I quit terminal and then I can't use `node` command in bash. Would anyone know why this is happening? Its rather infuriating. I think it may be something to do with the $PATH variable not being initialised in the right order or not at all.

I followed the 1st option https://gist.github.com/isaacs/579814

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: osx, 10.9, It works when I go to `~/local/bin` then `./node`, just can't get bash to see the command `node` or `npm`

Comment: What happens if you put the `$PATH` line in your `~/.profile` and then open a new terminal?

Comment: I put in `export PATH=$HOME/local/bin:$PATH` but no luck

Comment: `echo $PATH && source ~/.profile && echo $PATH`. Is there a difference between the two lines printed?

Comment: If I run the command, node works straight out of bash, otherwise it doesn't. How can I merge the 2?

Comment: So your problem isn't the text it's that your files are not being sourced when you open a new terminal. I just tried this on a friend's 10.8 and found that stuff in `~.bashrc` gets loaded fine but `~/.profile` doesn't. Which is a complete contradiction of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7780030/how-to-fix-terminal-not-loading-bashrc-on-os-x-lion). Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7780030/how-to-fix-terminal-not-loading-bashrc-on-os-x-lion) would help? Not being a mac person I don't know how to help more.

Comment: Add `export PATH=$HOME/local/bin:$PATH` in `~/.bash_profile` and `source ~/.bash_profile` or exit and open new terminal. Create `~/.bash_profile` it isn't available already.

Comment: Sorted it from @DavidWeldon s comment, I changed around the info in the files. Thanks man, really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @DavidWeldon and @Vinayak Mishra

Add export `PATH=$HOME/local/bin:$PATH` in `~/.bash_profile` and source `~/.bash_profile` or exit and open new terminal. Create `~/.bash_profile` it isn't available already.

If there is a problem with the $PATH, you can check it with:
`echo $PATH && source ~/.profile && echo $PATH`

If there are difference, files are not being called in the right order. Take a look at [this.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7780030/how-to-fix-terminal-not-loading-bashrc-on-os-x-lion)

Comment: Sweet! I'm glad we got that sorted out. :)

Comment: I dont know how to thank you for it or give you points or whatever man. But thanks.. :]