# PYTHONPATH disappears on Mac OS X after reopening Terminal

Tags: python, macos, terminal, pythonpath

I know there are plenty of questions related to PYTHONPATH but I couldn't find any answers to this specific problem.

I'm using Mac OS X Mountain Lion and just created my .bashrc file in my home directory (~/.bashrc) using the vi editor. I added the following line to the PYTHONPATH:

```
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

After this, when I do an `echo` of the PYTHONPATH, I get the above directory. Everything is hunky dory until...I quit the terminal and reopen it. That's when things get weird. I type in `echo $PYTHONPATH` and get a blank space!

Any advice on this issue?

Comment: Are you sure other stuff in .bashrc is running? Does it have +x permissions?

Comment: could this be the issue? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7780030/how-to-fix-terminal-not-loading-bashrc-on-os-x-lion

Comment: I just added a .bashrc file to my ~/ (Home) folder. So I don't get any errors per se. And the current settings for .bashrc are -rw-r--r--. So no +x permissions. Would +x permissions make any differences?

Answer (score 0):

By googling your problem, I found this post which should give you an explanation and a solution to your problem:
https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/119711/why-mac-os-x-dont-source-bashrc

Answer (score 0):

You could put that line in your ~/.bash_profile file, at which point it is run each time a new terminal is opened. (See [here](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/6.3/postlfs/profile.html) for more about this file).