# command not found: nodemon --- need helping adding directory to PATH

Tags: node.js, macos, path, npm, nodemon

I have looked at a lot of answers on here and I'm still not able to figure this one out. I am attempting to learn node again, but after my global install of nodemon (which completed successfully) I am getting **command not found: nodemon** when running **nodemon app.js**. A while back I moved my npm path to **/Users/mlefkowi/npm-global** for some reason. When I **echo $PATH**, that directory does not exists. This is what I get:

`/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin`

I have been able to add it to the $PATH, but when I close out Terminal it doesn't save. Should I move npm back to it's default directory? How can I get a path to save to $PATH?

Answer (score 2):

Edit your ~/.bashrc and add the following line:

```
export PATH="/Users/mlefkowi/npm-global:$PATH"
```

This assumes that `/Users/mlefkowi/npm-global/nodemon` is the path to the nodemon executable. If it's in a bin sub-directory off of npm-global, then change `/Users/mlefkowi/npm-global` to `/Users/mlefkowi/npm-global/bin`.

.bashrc is sourced every time your shell starts up, so this modification will stick for all new terminal sessions. After editing it for the first time, run `source ~/.bashrc` to update your PATH for that session.

Comment: I just ran **nano ~/.bashrc** and added **export PATH="/Users/mlefkowi/npm-global:$PATH"** to it (it is the only entry). The file is saved as **/Users/mlefkowi/.bashrc**. I then ran **source ~/.bashrc** and then **echo $PATH** and it was there. I then closed the terminal window, and ran **echo $PATH** again, and it's gone. But, the line is still in my **/Users/mlefkowi/.bashrc** file. What did I do wrong?

Comment: Your `.bashrc` should be run every time you open a new terminal. When you closed the terminal window, did you open a brand-new terminal window to test?

Comment: This is probably relevant to you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7780030/how-to-fix-terminal-not-loading-bashrc-on-os-x-lion I use iTerm, so it's possible that the default terminal uses `.bash_profile` instead.

Comment: Would it be easier to just change my npm install back to the default? Then my $PATH would already include the necessary paths, correct?

Comment: Tried the top two solutions in that link, neither are working

Comment: Alright I just reset my default directory and it's working now.