# Strange bug where PHP will not show ANSI colors when echoed from files on OSX

Tags: php, colors, command-line-interface, ansi-escape

I am encountering a bug where ANSI colors refuse to display when including a file.

The following bash command works as expected (straight bash):

```
echo -e "\033[31m some colored text \033[0m some white text" # Bash command displays fine
```

The following command run from the command line also works fine (php interpreter, command direct input via cli):

```
php -r 'echo "\033[31m some colored text \033[0m some white text \n";' # PHP from console displays fine
```

Including a file does not work.

Contents of test file:

```
<?php
//fails
$test = '"\033[31m some colored text \033[0m some white text \n"';
echo $test;
//escaped backslashes, also fails
$test = '"\\033[31m some colored text \\033[0m some white text \n"';
echo $test;
```

Including the file like this from the command line:

```
php index.php
```

Or including it like this from the command line:

```
php -f index.php
```

Always produces this:

```
"\033[31m some colored text \033[0m some white text \n""\033[31m some colored text \033[0m some white text \n"
```

Neither the line breaks nor the console colors display properly. What is causing this to choke specifically when a file runs as opposed to entering the command directly, either from bash or from PHP on the command line?

---

**Env:**
I am running PHP 7.0 in iTerm on OSX, but testing in the native terminal and zsh also fails.

[image: Screencap pictured for visualization purposes]

---

**I have already researched this issue and ruled out all of the following**

- This is OSX, not windows. The [known windows bug with ANSI colors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44047988/windows-10-console-colors-not-working-virtual-terminal-control-character-sequen) is not relevant.
- This is [not a problem with my console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1550288/os-x-terminal-colors). Colors do display in both BASH and PHP executed from the command line.
- This is [not a problem with the escape prefix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5947742/how-to-change-the-output-color-of-echo-in-linux/28938235#28938235). On my system `\e`, `\033`, and `\x1B` all display correctly. All of these have been attempted and none of them make any difference.
- This is not a problem with unescaped slashes. The given example demonstrates both `\033[` and `\\033[` failing.

---

**Edit:**

As some comments had pointed out, the above is double quoted. Single quoted also does not work, though other users indicate that it does work for them, which leads me to believe this is some kind of arcane misconfiguration issue and not a strict PHP language problem. Updated source as requested:

```
<?php
//fails
$test = "\033[31m some colored text \033[0m some white text \n";
echo $test;
//escaped backslashes, also fails
$test = "\\033[31m some colored text \\033[0m some white text \n";
echo $test;
```

Produces the same results anyways:

[image: Revised screencap]

Comment: Wait, you're not comparing like for like.  In the command-line version, you have a **double**-quoted string; In the index.php version, you have a **single**-quoted string.

Comment: The backslash character does not work in single quote strings.

Comment: It fails in double quoted strings also

Comment: But you put your double quotes inside a single quote!

Comment: Not for me :/ ...

Comment: Running it like this: `$test = "\033[31m some colored text \033[0m some white text \n";` produces exactly the same results.

Comment: I expect it's some kind of strange config issue if it is working for other people.

Comment: Not here.  Can you at least update your question (including the screenshot) so that you have the quoting correct.  As it stands, the answer to the posted question is "use double quotes" :/

Comment: Sure thing, one sec.

Comment: Yeah, there's something truly bizarre going on - you're even seeing the literal `\n`s in your output.  So not limited to ANSI escape sequences.

Comment: I hadn't noticed the `\n` thanks for pointing that out. Something is apparently getting in between the script and the command line output and escaping everything, but that gives me a few ideas what it might be. I'll update after I poke around a bit.

Comment: Try `\e[31m` instead of .`\033[31m` - or use a lib like [CliMate](https://github.com/thephpleague/climate) to save a whole lot of pain and ugly strings.

Comment: They are doing both. First `php -f index.php` to show results, then `cat index.php` is to display the file contents after the command fails.

Comment: I just ran the exact same thing in a Mint VM and it worked as expected. There's some strange config issue going on, possibly a docker issue or a homebrew issue in my main dev env.