# Why are ANSI color escape codes not working

Tags: java, string, colors, ansi-escape

I'm doing a word search, and the words that the user has found I wanted to mark in color, but I only get the printed string code and not the color. I have created a separate class to test if the colors work, but there is no way. How can I print colors?

```java
public class color {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String black="\033[30m"; 
        String red="\033[31m"; 
        String green="\033[32m"; 
        String yellow="\033[33m"; 
        String blue="\033[34m"; 
        String purple="\033[35m"; 
        String cyan="\033[36m"; 
        String white="\033[37m"; 
        String reset="\u001B[0m";

        System.out.println ();
        System.out.println (red + "Text string in red" + reset);
        System.out.println (green + "Text string in green" + reset);
        System.out.println (yellow + "Text string in yellow" + reset);
        System.out.println (white + "Text string in white" + reset);
        System.out.println (black + "Black text string" + reset + "(<- black text string that cannot be seen because my background is black)" + reset);
        System.out.println (blue + "Text string in blue" + reset);
        System.out.println (purple + "Magenta string" + reset);
        System.out.println (cyan + "Text string in cyan" + reset);
        System.out.println (reset + "Default color string" + reset);
        System.out.println ();
    }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps your console doesn't support colors?

Comment: HI, [31mText string in red[0m  is the result

Comment: And i use eclipse

Comment: @YoutuberMX eclipse is an IDE,not a console.

Comment: i use MAC OS X Sierra

Comment: Your demo app produces colorized output on my terminal.  Conclusion: the problem is with the console that is displaying the output ... for you.

Comment: If you are trying to get colors to work on a MacOS terminal windos; see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1550288/os-x-terminal-colors

Comment: export LESS=RSX

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ANSI color escape codes work on the assumption that there is some instance (let's call it "console") that receives characters (including the escape sequences), interprets them and displays glyphs with colors based on the interpretation.

If you send your output to such an ANSI-compatible console, then you'll get colored text, but the console you are using (the "Console" view in Eclipse?) apparently isn't ANSI-compatible.